# Compare sub string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has these columns

```
a_Max        b_Max
-------------------------
,LOG,RF,     ,GNB,LOG,SVC
,SVC,        ,RF,SVC,
,LOG         ,RF,GNB,
```

Is there an easy way to find if both `a_Max` and `b_Max` share any function name?

so ,LOG,RF, & ,GNB,LOG,SVC, share LOG algorithm

,SVC, & ,RF,SVC, share SVC algorithm

,LOG, & ,RF,GNB, no shared algorithms

```
a_Max        b_Max               ShareAlg
-----------------------------------------
,LOG,RF,     ,GNB,LOG,SVC,       1
,SVC,        ,RF,SVC,            1
,LOG,        ,RF,GNB,            0
```

I built a scalar function to compare both results with `string_split`, but this is way too slow. I wonder if there a faster way

Comment: You need to show us what you have already done in order for a faster solution to be offered. Also if you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier for people to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scalar functions can be a drain on performance.   If you **must** use a function, consider a Table-Valued Function first.

There are penalties for storing delimited data... **SOMETHING WILL HAVE TO GET PARSED SOONER OR LATER.**

However, here is an option that does not require a SVF or TVF.

NOTE: Not seeing your function, it is hard to say if this will be more performant.

**Example**

```
Select * 
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply  ( Select SharAlg = count(*)
                 from string_split(a_Max,',') B1
                 Join string_split(b_Max,',') B2 on B1.Value=B2.Value and B1.Value<>''
              ) B
```

**Results**

```
a_Max       b_Max           SharAlg
,LOG,RF,    ,GNB,LOG,SVC    1
,SVC,       ,RF,SVC,        1
,LOG        ,RF,GNB,        0
```